# cox analysis time dependant R

Tags: r, cox-regression, timed-events

I create my table to make an analysis cox survival time-dependant (with t start and t stop for each ID)

my variable dependant is death and my variable independent is a score

So i look the document R about this type of analysis but when i run the code to have an HR and confidence interval my sample is multiple by 2 ( like they considered all my row as a sample)

I'm wondering if the following code is right to make analysis survival time dependant

```
coxph(Surv(tStart, tStop, DEATH) ~ score ,
        data =df_timedep, cluster = ID)
```

Do you know if it's ok with this code ?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the structure of the data (even if it's just a few rows) and the output? Right now it looks like your code is correct.

Comment: If there is only one interval per ID, then the 'cluster' argument is not needed.

Comment: i'm wondering the utility of cluster ? because without it i obtained the same results and for some ID i have two interval @IRTFM